# Reason for the error in this form?

Tags: jquery, mysql, forms

I am using this code and Im getting the alert message: "Form save failed, please contact your administrator"

Im trying to understand the reason for the erro. I am not the one who created the code Im just trying it out for educational purpose:.

I ahve tested my database connection and its works well. I am also sure that the form fields are properly and completely filled out before I hit the submit button.

Can you enlighten me of possible reason.

here is the link to the form that I have uploaded in our site:
http://www.ssagroup.com/_form/aj.html

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#personal_details").submit(function() {
        processDetails();
        return false;
    });
});

function processDetails() {
    var errors = '';

    // Validate name
    var name = $("#personal_details [name='name']").val();
    if (!name) {
        errors += ' - Please enter a name\n';
    }
    // Validate age range
    var age_range = $("#personal_details [name='age_range']").val();
    if (!age_range) {
        errors += ' - Please select and age range\n';
    }
    // Validate sports selection
    var sports = $("#personal_details [name='sports[]']:checked").length;
    if (!sports) {
        errors += ' - Please select your favourite sports\n';
    }

    if (errors) {
        errors = 'The following errors occurred:\n' + errors;
        alert(errors);
        return false;
    } else {
        // Submit our form via Ajax and then reset the form
        $("#personal_details").ajaxSubmit({success:showResult});
        return false;
    }

}

function showResult(data) {
    if (data == 'save_failed') {
        alert('Form save failed, please contact your administrator');
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#personal_details").clearForm().clearFields().resetForm();
        alert('Form save success');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its an error on the backeend. The result from the ajax call is `save_failed` which triggers `if (data == 'save_failed') {`

The reasons for why it failed on teh backend could be many.... and no way to determine, you would have to post the php code

Answer (score 1):

Hiya please do this remove spaces: can you flick jsfiddle hope you are sourcing right libraries.

I am lil hesistant to click on the external link

Anyhoo below should help ;)

```
 $("#personal_details [name='name']").val();
                     ^----------------------------Sapce here
```

Try this

```
 $("#personal_details[name='name']").val();
```

**Further** Seems to be working here:

[image]

Comment: Yes.. Im so sorry its a very blatant error on my side... I have forgotten to create a table in the mysql where the field form value will go into.. so many thanks for your replies...

Comment: @ARGO ha ha ha ha ha `:)` no worries man, lol have a good one! been there done that! :P